# dbm 35 Resource temporarily unavailable on OSX python 2.7

Tags: python, macos, flask

I am using the Flask-WeRobot plugin and I am seeing an error being thrown here:

```
class FileStorage(SessionStorage):
    """
    FileStorage 会把你的 Session 数据以 dbm 形式储存在文件中。

    :param filename: 文件名， 默认为 ``werobot_session``
    """
    def __init__(self, filename='werobot_session'):
        print filename
        try:
          self.db = dbm.open(filename, "c")
        except Exception, e:
          print e
          raise e
```

This is what is being outputted:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 18, in <module>
    another_robot = WeRoBot(token='abcdefg', enable_session=True)
  File "/Users/vng/Dropbox/Code/Paw/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_werobot.py", line 42, in __init__
    super(WeRoBot, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/vng/Dropbox/Code/Paw/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werobot/robot.py", line 47, in __init__
    filename=os.path.abspath("werobot_session")
  File "/Users/vng/Dropbox/Code/Paw/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werobot/session/filestorage.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.db = dbm.open(filename, "c")
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/anydbm.py", line 85, in open
    return mod.open(file, flag, mode)
gdbm.error: (35, 'Resource temporarily unavailable')
```

At first I thought it would have something to do with permissions, but changing the file, `werobot_session` didn't work.

I am on OSX running python 2.7. This code **works** on my ubuntu production server.

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: What happens if you give the full path to `werobot_session`? It looks like the file is not being found.

Comment: @MattDMo The full path is `/Users/vng/Dropbox/Code/Paw/paw/werobot_session` and I can `cat` it just fine.

Comment: Yes, I know that. What I meant was you should put the full path to the file in your `__init__` function: `def __init__(self, filename="/Users/vng/Dropbox/Code/Paw/paw/werobot_session"):`

Comment: And why did you change your traceback?

Comment: @MattDMo filename is already `"/Users/vng/Dropbox/Code/Paw/paw/werobot_session"` I tried manually changing it but it didn't work. 

Also the traceback was referring to the modified version I was writing, which can confuse readers thinking that it was location not found rather than the real GDBM error

Answer (score 0):

We find this bug too and we are working on it now.
It seems that it's a bug of gdbm. And everything works fine on linux.
You can check this issue for further information.
https://github.com/whtsky/WeRoBot/issues/102